# R Studio will only plot box plots

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R for some very simple data visualization (*note: I am working within R Studio). I am loading a csv file containing two time series of daily prices, with column headers 'price1', and 'price2'. All I am looking for here is to create a line plot of each time series, but I am returned a box plot every time. For example, attempting to plot time series 'price1' looks as follows in my code:

```
#Load csv into dataframe
data <- read.csv("pathtofile.csv")

#Plot time series 'price1'
plot(data["price1"])
```

The problem seems extremely straight forward, but I'm relatively new to using R, so I am unsure if there is a simple syntax mistake here that I'm not catching.

**edit**

**output of str(data):**

```
'data.frame':   1382 obs. of  6 variables:
$ time : Factor w/ 1382 levels "00:00:00","00:01:00",..: 1022 1023 1024 
1025 1026 1027 1028 1029 1030 1031 ...
$ feb  : num  57 57 57 57 57 ...
$ jun  : num  57.7 57.7 57.7 57.7 57.7 ...
$ X    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ ret_f: num  0.035 0 -0.015 0.03 0 -0.02 0.02 -0.025 0.01 0 ...
$ ret_j: num  0.01 0 0.005 0 -0.005 0 0.005 0 0 -0.015 ...
```

**output of dput(data[1:10,]):**

```
structure(list(time = structure(1022:1031, .Label = c("00:00:00", 
"00:01:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00", "00:06:00", 
"00:07:00", "00:08:00", "00:09:00", "00:10:00", "00:11:00", "00:12:00", 
"00:13:00", "00:14:00", "00:15:00", "00:16:00", "00:17:00", "00:18:00", 
"00:19:00", "00:20:00", "00:21:00", "00:22:00", "00:23:00", "00:24:00", 
"00:25:00", "00:26:00", "00:27:00", "00:28:00", "00:29:00", "00:30:00", 
"00:31:00", "00:32:00", "00:33:00", "00:34:00", "00:35:00", "00:36:00", 
"00:37:00", "00:38:00", "00:39:00", "00:40:00", "00:41:00", "00:42:00", 
"00:43:00", "00:44:00", "00:45:00", "00:46:00", "00:47:00", "00:48:00", 
"00:49:00", "00:50:00", "00:51:00", "00:52:00", "00:53:00", "00:54:00", 
"00:55:00", "00:56:00", "00:57:00", "00:58:00", "00:59:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:01:00", "01:02:00", "01:03:00", "01:04:00", "01:05:00", "01:06:00", 
"01:07:00", "01:08:00", "01:09:00", "01:10:00", "01:11:00", "01:12:00", 
"01:13:00", "01:14:00", "01:15:00", "01:16:00", "01:17:00", "01:18:00", 
"01:19:00", "01:20:00", "01:21:00", "01:22:00", "01:23:00", "01:24:00", 
"01:25:00", "01:26:00", "01:27:00", "01:28:00", "01:29:00", "01:30:00", 
....
"57.23"), class = "factor"), feb = c(56.95, 56.985, 56.985, 56.97, 
57, 57, 56.98, 57, 56.975, 56.985), jun = c(57.69, 57.7, 57.7, 
57.705, 57.705, 57.7, 57.7, 57.705, 57.705, 57.705), X = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ret_f = c(0.035, 0, -0.015, 
0.03, 0, -0.02, 0.02, -0.025, 0.01, 0), ret_j = c(0.01, 0, 0.005, 
0, -0.005, 0, 0.005, 0, 0, -0.015)), row.names = c("18:00:00", 
"18:01:00", "18:02:00", "18:03:00", "18:04:00", "18:05:00", "18:06:00", 
"18:07:00", "18:08:00", "18:09:00"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you paste into your question the output of `str(data)` and the output of `dput(data[1:10, ])`.

Comment: This could happen if `price1` was read as a factor even though it should be numeric.  The most common reasons I've seen for this is having commas in the numbers or having missing values designated by a character.

Comment: @eipi10 added the outputs to my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to either specify 'dummy' x values or specify the plot type.

try:

```
plot(data["price1"], type='l')
```

or

```
plot(seq_along(data["price1"]), data["price1"], type='l')
```

Comment: I've tried using plot(data["price1"], type='l'), but this just returns a box plot with a straight line across it. plot(seq_along(data["price1"]), data["price1"], type='l') doesn't return anything, just a bunch of errors :(

Comment: your data is not being read correctly.  You can see from the outputs that you have all kinds of weird headers for your data.  Are you sure its comma-separated and not some other delimiter?  It could be that there are more commas than there are real columns